# Uploading a file into Nexus from Jenkins pipeline is not working

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This doesn't work:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', passwordVariable: 'ABCD', usernameVariable: 'XYZ')]) {
    dir("build") {            
        sh "curl -u $XYZ:$ABCD --upload-file xyz.tar.gz https://mnpqr/repository/abc/$BRANCH_DIR/xyz.tar.gz"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xyz/build@tmp/durable-71c2368a/script.sh: line 1: VG7cJ: No such file or directory
```

But this works:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', passwordVariable: 'ABCD', usernameVariable: 'XYZ')]) {
    dir("build") {            
        sh 'curl -u $XYZ:$ABCD --upload-file xyz.tar.gz https://mnpqr/repository/abc/$BRANCH_DIR/xyz.tar.gz'
    }
}
```

I want to interpolate more data into the sh script but I cannot as its failing with double quotes.

Comment: Please update the code or the error message in the question to align with each other. Also, where/how is the variable `BRANCH_DIR` defined?

Comment: @MattSchuchard env.BRANCH_DIR = env.BRANCH_NAME.replace("/", "_"). Its defined in the pipeline before this step is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful to distinguish the variable scopes:

- environment variables set in your script
- environment variables set by Jenkins processes
- local variables not available in forked shell process

They all have to be handled in a different way when replacing them in your double-quoted string:

```
node {
    stage('My stage') {
        // local variable scope
        varContent = "Variable content"

        // environment variable set up in script
        env.envContent = "Environment content"

        // environment variable available in shell script
        withEnv(["BRANCH_NAME=myBranch"]) {
            sh("echo ${varContent} XX ${env.envContent} XX \${envContent} XX \${BRANCH_NAME} XX ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
        }
    }
}
```

In the example you see all of the three types. Let's have a closer look at the shell command:

```
sh("echo ${varContent} XX ${env.envContent} XX \${envContent} XX \${BRANCH_NAME} XX ${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
```

1. `${varContent}` is a variable from local script scope it is replaced *before* the string is written to a temporary shell script
2. `${env.envContent}` and `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` handle environment variables that have already been set beforehand, as if they were a "local scope" variable
3. `\${envContent}` and `\${BRANCH_NAME}` are the actual environment variables. The backslash escapes the dollar sign, and the shell script will contain shell variable placeholders `${envContent}` and `${BRANCH_NAME}` that will be replaced at shell script run time.

Running the above script will show the following output:
[image: Jenkins build output]